# Undefined errors causing go test to fail

Tags: go, testing

I'm running into an issue when running `go test` with a test I've set up. There is method in another file (not in the test file) that throws the following errors when I run `go test`:

```
# GoPackage [GoPackage.test]
./io.go:100:17: undefined: unix.EpollEvent
./io.go:101:22: undefined: unix.EpollEvent
./io.go:121:20: undefined: unix.EpollCreate1
./io.go:135:22: undefined: unix.EPOLLPRI
./io.go:140:16: undefined: unix.EpollCtl
./io.go:141:36: undefined: unix.EPOLL_CTL_ADD
./io.go:145:19: undefined: unix.EpollWait
FAIL    GoPackage [build failed]
```

Note: io.go has an import for `golang.org/x/sys/unix` which is where these unix syscalls come from. One example in io.go is:

`var event unix.EpollEvent`

If I comment out the original method and create a dummy version and run the test, the test runs successfully.

I'm building/running the test on a MacOS and I've read the syscalls aren't available on Mac (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30539).

Is there a way to get around this issue of testing a go build on a Mac? Is there a way to suppress these messages from preventing the test from running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to switch out which version of that file is included depending on the platform, so e.g.

> io_linux.go

```
//go:build linux
// +build linux


import (
    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

func DoSomething() {
    unix.EpollCreate(10)
}
```

> io_other.go

```
//go:build !linux
// +build !linux

func DoSomething() {
    // do nothing, EpollCreate not supported
}
```

and now when you build, if it's linux, it will include `io_linux.go`, otherwise it will include `io_other.go`